# osmnx which_result meaning

Tags: python, osmnx

This is a pretty straightforward question when I write

```
G = ox.graph_from_place()
```

I have a parameter called `which_result`, I have seen it's definition in the documentation, but I still can't understand what it does.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens some queries return several results. As stated in the documentation for the method [`graph_from_place`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.graph_from_place):

> (...)
>   Alternatively, you might try to vary the which_result parameter to use a different geocode result. For example, the first geocode result (ie, the default) might resolve to a point geometry, but the second geocode result for this query might resolve to a polygon, in which case you can use graph_from_place with which_result=2.

It is mainly used by the [`gdf_from_place`](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/f5eb1fc4f18c1816987de7f0db8d35690dc65f41/osmnx/core.py#L40) function, which relies on [`osm_polygon_download`](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/f5eb1fc4f18c1816987de7f0db8d35690dc65f41/osmnx/downloader.py#L271) where this number becomes the argument `limit` as:

> max number of results to return

and which is used as a parameter by the [`nominatim_request`](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/f5eb1fc4f18c1816987de7f0db8d35690dc65f41/osmnx/downloader.py#L312) function, which in turns (and finally) relies on the Nominatim API, especially in its [result-limitation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#result-limitation) part where it is clearly described, for search queries, as:

> Limit the number of returned results. (Default: 10, Maximum: 50)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was an awesome explanation, I finally understood !!!!